# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Communications link failure, when running spring boot application and mysql image in docker container

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am working on spring boot application with Mysql and using hibernate ORM.Application is running fine without Docker But when same app i am running in docker with application and mysql docker imgae with docker-compose, mysql service is running fine but app is failing.

## Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"  
services:task-management-service

image: task-management  
 ports:- "13000:8088"
 networks: - task-management-nwk  
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  mysqldb:  
    image: mysql:8  
    networks:
      - task-management-nwk  
    environment:  
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******  
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=task_management  

networks:  
  task-management-nwk:
```

## this is my application.properties

## database

```
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
db.url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/task_management  
db.username: root  
db.password: *****
```

## Here is excpeption log -

```
Recreating task-management_mysqldb_1 ... done
Recreating task-management_task-management-service_1 ... done
Attaching to task-management_mysqldb_1, task-management_task-management-service_1
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07 08:23:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.18-1debian9 started.
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07 08:23:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07 08:23:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.18-1debian9 started.
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07T08:23:06.774373Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default
. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07T08:23:06.774471Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 1
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07T08:23:07.173060Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.  
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07T08:23:07.177496Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is acc
essible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.  
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07T08:23:07.193039Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/
mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysqldb_1                  | 2019-12-07T08:23:07.381165Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '
::' port: 33060
task-management-service_1  |
task-management-service_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
task-management-service_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
task-management-service_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
task-management-service_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
task-management-service_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
task-management-service_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
task-management-service_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)
task-management-service_1  |
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:08.604  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.t.demo.TaskManagementApplication       : Starting TaskManagementApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSH
OT on fd39279d538e with PID 1 (/Task-Management.jar started by root in /)
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:08.610  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.t.demo.TaskManagementApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default p
rofiles: default
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:09.700  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAUL
T mode.
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:09.730  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18ms
. Found 0 repository interfaces.  
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.222  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation
.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed b
y all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.572  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 12000 (http)  
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.584  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.584  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.657  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationConte
xt
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.657  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization compl
eted in 1959 ms
task-management-service_1  | Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically regist
ered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:10.830  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:11.041  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.
0.Final}  
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:11.221  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query
metadata : Communications link failure  
task-management-service_1  |
task-management-service_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.  
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:11.233  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.
MySQL5Dialect
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:11.850  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01  
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:11.851 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure
task-management-service_1  |
task-management-service_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
task-management-service_1  | 2019-12-07 08:23:11.855  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initializat
ion - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expres
sed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
```

Comment: Spring Boot can't connect to MySQL.  `mysqldb` likely only works inside of the Docker Compose network.  Have you tried exposing port 3306 on the host, so that you can connect to it?

Comment: I tried exposing port 3306  but didn't work.

Comment: If you're running your Spring Boot app outside of Docker Compose, try using `localhost` instead of `mysqldb` in your JDBC URL.